# On SharePoint Online is there a way to change a default "square logo" to a "fixed" sized company logo"

Tags: sharepoint-online, branding, site-logo

I am given these default square logos with the first initial of a site name and I would much rather replace it with the company logo which comes to the size of 400x 128. It lets me upload the company logo  but even if my company logo is 400 x 128 it still gets truncated to 128 by 128 just the same, making it unrecognizable and futile.
Without content editors WP , how is this accomplished?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand you are talking about the Modern page of Team or Communication site.

Option 1: You have to find or create a company logo which actually suits the Square placeHolder given by Microsoft for Logo. hope this you might not want to do.

Option 2 : You have to use SPFx extension to customize the Header
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions

Option 3: if you want to have modern script editor webpart which supported by Modern pages then use below link
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor
using this you can embed javascript html and css according to your need as you were doing in Classic pages.

Hope these information resolve your concern